# SQLPLUSでSQLファイル実行時にマイナスの値を返したい

Tags: sql, oracle

SQL PLUS実行時にマイナスの値を返却値としたいです。
実行結果として以下のようになればよいのですが、

```
> sqlplus -L user/pass@sid @DATA.SQL
> echo $?
> -1
```

単純にDATA.SQLファイルに
EXIT -1
としても、以下のようにSQL PLUSの仕様上不可能のような記述がありましたが、SPなどを利用して実現可能でしょうか。方法があれば教えてください。OSはRedhatLinuxです。

> **EXIT（戻り値）の上限**
>
> UNIX 系の EXIT のステータスコードは 下位の 8ビットでマスクされるために 256 以上の数値を指定しても違う値に変換される。特に
>   256 の倍数は 下位 8ビットでマスクされると 0 になるので正常終了と誤認する危険がある。 Windows 系だからといって 256
>   以上の戻り値を使用するとプラットフォームの互換性が無くなるので控える方がよい。

[SQL*Plus > EXIT、QUIT](http://www.shift-the-oracle.com/sqlplus/command/exit.html)

Comment: すみません、リファレンスのリンクが既にあることを見落として編集してしまいました。ロールバックしましたので元に戻っています。

Answer (score 1):

回答ではないのですが、シェル(bash/zsh)の `exit status` に関して少し書きます。

```
$ bash -c 'exit -1'; echo $?
255
$ bash -c 'exit -2'; echo $?
254
$ bash -c 'exit -3'; echo $?
253
```

上記の例は `bash` ですが、`zsh` でも同様の結果になります。

> man bash(1)
>
> EXIT STATUS
>
> The exit status of an executed command is the value returned by the waitpid system call or equivalent function. **Exit statuses fall between 0 and 255**, though, as explained below, the shell may use values above 125 specially.

exit status は `unsigned char` として扱われていますので、負の値になることはありません。何らかの方法で sqlplus に -1 の 戻り値を持たせたとしても、シェルでの exit status は 255 となってしまいます。まぁ、

> exit status 255 は -1 と見做す

とでもすれば良いのかもしれませんが、もしかすると sqlplus がエラーなどで exit status 255 を返す場合も無いとは言えず、適切ではないと思われます。

Comment: 補足 ： 左端を負数ビットにした2の補数形式での-1は
 1111 ～省略～ 1111 1111 と桁数分1が並ぶ事になります。
8ビットマスクによって下位8ビット以外が切り捨てられて
 1111 1111これを10進数に直すと255になります。
 -2は～1111 1110　で254に -3は～1111 1101で253になります。
桁落ちしている状態ですので511、767、1023、1777といった
 (256*n)-1 の数字が入ると255になってしまいます。
本文中にある通り、255を-1とみなすのは避けたほうが宜しいかと思います。

Comment: @通りすがりのIT技術者 コメントありがとうございます。重要な情報だと思いますので、できれば通りすがりのIT技術者さんの回答欄に追記していただけないでしょうか。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

リターンコードに限定すると8ビットでマスクされると記述されているので不可能でしょう。

検索してみると幾つかのUNIX系のOSも同様のQ&A記述がありますね。  
無理に負数ビットを立ててもマスクされると255辺りになってしまうようです。

リターンコードとしては無理ですが、シェルの標準出力や  
select句の実行結果としてなら無理やり返せますね。

```
set ret=`sqlplus -S user/pass@sid ` << END
set head off;
set termout off
@DATA.SQL
set termout on
select '-1' from dual;
exit;
END
```

の後で

```
echo $ret
```

するとかね。

---

**追記** ： 私の回答では動作部分を省略して答えだけにしていたので、  
以下は実験結果を記入したheliac2001さんの回答に対する補足のつもりでした。

「8ビットでマスク」というのは2進数のビット演算によって  
下位8ビット以外を切り捨てるということを意味します。

**-1**を「左端を負数ビットにした2の補数形式」の2進数で表すと  
 **1111 ～省略～ 1111 1111** と桁数分1が並ぶ事になります。

8ビットマスクによって下位8ビット以外が切り捨てられると **1111 1111** となります。  
これを10進数に直すと**255**になり、**EXIT -1** の結果にこの数値が入ります。

他の負数はこうなります。  
 **-2**(10進数) = **1111 ～省略～1111 1110**(2進数) -> 下位8ビットでマスク -> **254**(10進数)
 **-3**(10進数) = **1111 ～省略～1111 1101**(2進数) -> 下位8ビットでマスク -> **253**(10進数)

上位ビットが全て桁落ちしている状態ですので**511**、**767**、**1023**、**1777**といった  
「**256の倍数 -1**」の数字が入ると**255**になってしまいます。  
この辺は他の数値でも同じ状況です。

以上の理由で**255**を **-1**とみなすのは避けたほうが宜しいかと思います。